# Can't connect to Chrome Remote Desktop on Ubuntu 18

Tags: remote-desktop

I've made these changes here: https://superuser.com/questions/778028/configuring-chrome-remote-desktop-with-ubuntu-gnome-14-04/850359#850359.

It used to work a few months back. Now, when I try it, however, it fails to start, with this error:

```
Launching X server and X session.
Launching host process
['/opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/chrome-remote-desktop-host', '--host-config=-', '--audio-pipe-name=/home/gabriel/.config/chrome-remote-desktop/pulseaudio#a8a25a6f37/fifo_output', '--ssh-auth-sockname=/tmp/chromoting.gabriel.ssh_auth_sock', '--signal-parent']
wait() returned (6180,256)
Host process terminated
Host exited with status 1.
Failure count for 'X server' is now 6
Failure count for 'session' is now 0
Failure count for 'host' is now 0
Waiting before relaunching
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the "fix": I've had to repeatedly uninstall Chrome Remote Desktop after each use [because of the problems it's causing with auto-mounting disks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196248/automount-when-clicking-on-disks-in-gui-file-manager-suddenly-stopped-working-in). Therefore, for the most part, I've simply switched to [NoMachine](https://www.nomachine.com), which works very well on Linux, with zero bugs I have seen.

### Related:

1. [My answer] [Automount when clicking on disks in GUI file manager suddenly stopped working in Ubuntu. ("Unable to mount...Not authorized to perform operation.")](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196248/automount-when-clicking-on-disks-in-gui-file-manager-suddenly-stopped-working-in/1196273#1196273)

Answer (score 0):

I modified the script a bit and got it working under Ubuntu 18.04 with latest updates. heres my changes

https://pastebin.com/rT4fDb7r

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a try when able.