# How to set up NoMachine in Ubuntu with key based authentication?

Tags: remote-desktop, nomachine

How do you set up NoMachine on Ubuntu?

Why Nomachine?

On Windows, I love using Chrome Remote Desktop for remote logins, and it works great. But, on Linux, I just have problem after problem with Chrome Remote Desktop, and it's super buggy:

1. It stops me from mounting and using plugged in USB disks or drives: [Automount when clicking on disks in GUI file manager suddenly stopped working in Ubuntu. ("Unable to mount...Not authorized to perform operation.")](https://askubuntu.com/q/1196248/327339)
2. It stops me from changing my printer settings: [Ubuntu 18.04 gnome settings: how to fix "System policy prevents changes. Contact your system administrator" on 2nd user which is already an admin](https://askubuntu.com/q/1227842/327339)
3. I get roughly one usage per reinstall of Chrome Remote Desktop: [Can't connect to Chrome Remote Desktop on Ubuntu 18](https://askubuntu.com/q/1189710/327339)
4. etc.

So, I've heard good things about NoMachine and want to give it a shot. But, I want to use key-based authentication and disable password-based authentication for improved security. So, how do I set up NoMachine to do this?

Comment: @user535733, I just wanted to drop a Q&A with some concise info. all in one place, specific to Ubuntu. Finding the details on things like enabling key-based logins and disabling password-based logins can otherwise be a bit tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I originally posted these instructions on my [eRCaGuy_dotfiles](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles) repo here: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/tree/master/NoMachine

If you ever need to ssh in, I've documented [my various ssh notes here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/tree/master/home/.ssh).

## NoMachine Readme

NoMachine is an *excellent* remote login program, with *excellent* file-sharing/mount abilities and *excellent* cross-platform support for Windows, Mac, Linux, iOS, Android, Raspberry Pi, and ARM. It is *not* open source, but is no cost to use (personal use only--businesses must pay).

https://www.nomachine.com/

## Setup

### Download:

https://www.nomachine.com/download

### To enable key-based authentication to server:

References:
READ THESE!

1. [How to set up key based authentication with NX protocol](https://www.nomachine.com/AR02L00785)
2. [Generating a new SSH key](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)

Essentially, just add your public key to the `$HOME/.nx/config/authorized.crt` file on the server. If the file doesn't exist, create it. Set its permissions to 0600. Here's one example of commands to do that:

**1) Run from *client*:**

Generate a new private/public key pair from the *client*; run this from the client:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your personal comment or email"
```

Copy the *public* (.pub) key only from client to server; run this from the client; notice the renaming of the file on the destination to avoid conflict with keys already generated on the server:

```
scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub username@server_hostname_or_ip:~/.ssh/id_rsa_nxclient.pub
```

**2) Run from *server*:**

Add public key now on server to proper NoMachine file; run this from the server:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa_nxclient.pub >> ~/.nx/config/authorized.crt
```

And lastly set this file's permissions to 0600 to enable read/write on this file ONLY for the user (owner) of this file, for security:

```
chmod 0600 ~/.nx/config/authorized.crt
```

### To *disable* password-based login to server:

NB: Do NOT do this until key-based authentication is set up & verified to be working, or else you'll lose the ability to remotely connect via NoMachine, & have to manually fix it remotely over ssh, or locally!

References:
(Not exactly addressing this question, but indirectly helpful in figuring it out)

1. [Prevent password authentication with NX protocol and key-based authentication](https://forums.nomachine.com/topic/prevent-password-authentication-with-nx-protocol-and-key-based-authentication)
2. [The server.cfg and node.cfg files explained (for server v. 4 and later)](https://www.nomachine.com/AR02N00877)

Note: On Linux, server.cfg is located here: "/usr/NX/etc/server.cfg".

*On the server*, edit server.cfg (`sudo gedit /usr/NX/etc/server.cfg`) and find this section:

```
#
# Specify how clients will have to authenticate to the server, by
# default all the available methods are supported. This corresponds
# to value all. To specify a subset of methods use a comma-separated
# list.
#
# Supported methods for connections by NX protocol are:
# NX-password   : Password authentication.
# NX-private-key: Key-based authentication.
# NX-kerberos   : Kerberos ticket-based authentication.
#
# Supported method for connections by SSH protocol is:
# SSH-system    : All methods supported for the system login.
#                 SSH authentication methods for the system login
#                 have to be set on the system for example in the
#                 PAM configuration.
#
# For example:
# AcceptedAuthenticationMethods NX-private-key,SSH-system
#
# This key has to be used in conjunction with ClientConnectionMethod.
# See also the EnableNXClientAuthentication key for enabling SSL
# client authentication for connections by NX protocol.
#
#AcceptedAuthenticationMethods all
```

Now, just below this commented-out line indicating the default setting:

```
#AcceptedAuthenticationMethods all
```

Add this line to change the setting to allow ONLY key-based authentication:

```
AcceptedAuthenticationMethods NX-private-key
```

Then restart the NoMachine server (https://www.nomachine.com/TR11N07362):

```
sudo /usr/NX/bin/nxserver --restart
```

Now try to connect remotely using NoMachine with password-based authentication, and you should see the following error in the GUI program:

```
Ooops! The session negotation failed. Error: Authentication method NX-password is not allowed on this server
```

If you saw the above error you have successfully disabled password authentication logins! Now test your key-based authentication to ensure it still works.

### To connect from outside your network

To connect to NoMachine from outside your home, you must either VPN into your local network, or open up port forwarding through your firewall in your modem.

To do the port-forwarding, connect to your modem via its IP address in your browser, and through your settings, map some external port, such as `10000`, to your internal computer's IP and port with NoMachine on it. Those details are for another Q&A sometime...

The default port to your NoMachine server is `4000`, I believe. Click on the NoMachine icon in the top-right in Ubuntu, go to "Show the Service Status" --> click "Server Preferences" tab on the right --> see the "Port" there for your NoMachine server.

Done.

Comment: @user68186, `4000`, I believe. Click on the NoMachine icon in the top-right in Ubuntu, go to "Show the Service Status" --> click "Server Preferences" tab on the right --> see the "Port" there for your NoMachine server.

Comment: Setup on Ubuntu 20.04 but get a login screen wanting password. Any ideas how to prevent that from happening?  We don't provide users with passwords, so users are stuck on that screen preventing them access. Tried the following, but still getting login screen: 

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen true`, `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false`, `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 0`

Comment: @DennisHoer, yeah I don't know. Try asking a new question. When you do, leave a comment here with the link to that new question.

Comment: Webplayer was setup for password causing this issue. Stopping webplayer seemed to make the lock screen not pop up.

Answer (score 0):

NoMachine Knowledge Base has this documented under **How to set up key based authentication with NX protocol** which Gabriel Staples mentions in his answer:

- https://kb.nomachine.com/AR02L00785

But there is a BUG that requires an additional step to uncheck **Import the private key to the connection file** checkbox on client to make it work:

- https://kb.nomachine.com/TR05S10271